# In Indonesia, are research grants extra income that go directly into academics' pockets?

Tags: funding, salary

The average base salary for academics in Indonesia seems to be quite low. It seems likely that they receive various extra incomes that can be higher than their base salary; otherwise, they won't be able to survive. Are research grants one of these incomes? How do universities in Indonesia manage research grants?

Comment: I don't know about Indonesia, but in many countries academics can have industry contracts from which they can get extra income.

Answer (score 3):

I did my advanced studies in southeast Asia. One of my professors was from Indonesia. When I was talking to him one time he shared that when applying for a grant the researcher should put in a "consulting fee". This fee covered the researchers time. 
I can't say if this is standard practice but it is first person testimony from the country.